# Angular9 DHX Spreadsheet - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setImmediate' of undefined

Tags: angular, spreadsheet

Trying to use the DHX Spreadsheet and this is the issue i faced:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘setImmediate’ of undefined
at spreadsheet.min.js:12
at Object. (spreadsheet.min.js:12)
at Object. (spreadsheet.min.js:12)
at n (spreadsheet.min.js:12)
at Object. (spreadsheet.min.js:12)
at n (spreadsheet.min.js:12)
at Object. (spreadsheet.min.js:12)
at n (spreadsheet.min.js:12)
at Object. (spreadsheet.min.js:12)
at n (spreadsheet.min.js:12)
at spreadsheet.min.js:12
at spreadsheet.min.js:12
at push…/node_modules/dhx-spreadsheet/codebase/spreadsheet.min.js.dhx_legacy. (spreadsheet.min.js:12)
at Object…/node_modules/dhx-spreadsheet/codebase/spreadsheet.min.js (spreadsheet.min.js:12)
at webpack_require (bootstrap:79)
at Module…/src/app/spreadsheet/spreadsheet.component.ts (spreadsheet.component.ts:1)
```

I am unable to even load the project at all due to this error coming from the library.
Any solution to this?

Here’s my github link to the above mentioned issue:

https://github.com/patrickklze/trying_dhx_spreadsheet_angular.git